# File is not found in MEIPASS Pyinstaller (but was working initially)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a program that sends some data to GCS in a while loop, which requires a JSON credential file, it roughly looks like the following:

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path


GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FP = "pos-service-account.json"

IS_INSTALLER = getattr(sys, "frozen", False) and hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS")
if IS_INSTALLER:
    GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FP = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FP)



def send_data(data, credential_fp: Path = Path(GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FP)):
    if not credential_fp.is_file():
        msg = f"Google service account key json file: {str(credential_fp)!r} is not found!\nPWD files:\n{list(Path.cwd().glob('*'))}"
        raise FileNotFoundError(msg)

    # some function post data to cloud storage
    post_to_gcs(data)


def main():
    while True:
        data = ...
        send_data(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I packaged using one file with the following command:
`pyinstaller --onefile -w .\main.py --add-data 'pos-service-account.json;.'`

Then when I clicked on the .exe file on windows, it was working fine, I could see the data posted by this program. However, I came back after a few days, I got the file not found error:

```
 Google service account key json file: 'C:\\Users\\POS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI30522\\pos-service-account.json' is not found!
```

this does not make sense to me as the program was working at the beginning, which means it did find the json file, I'm still trying to replicate the error, but so far my suspicion is:

- Does the `sys._MEIPASS` directory ever change? e.g. if the computer goes to sleep and comes back on (I'm going to test it), I could see how my script would fail if the `_MEIPASS` changes when the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the MEIPASS folder changes it's name often, so hardcoding that file location is a bad idea. Instead save the file relative to the `__file__` path variable so it will always be referring to the currently running programs location.

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FP = "pos-service-account.json"

CREDENTIAL = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), GOOGLE_SERVICES_ACCOUNT_FP)


def send_data(data, credential_fp=CREDENTIAL):
    if not credential_fp.is_file():
        msg = f"Google service account key json file: {str(credential_fp)!r} is not found!\nPWD files:\n{list(Path.cwd().glob('*'))}"
        raise FileNotFoundError(msg)

    # some function post data to cloud storage
    post_to_gcs(data)


def main():
    while True:
        data = ...
        send_data(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, interesting... 1. why would `sys._MEIPASS` change while the script is running? 2. if the `sys._MEIPASS` (which I understood as the folder that holds the json file) changes, why `__file__` can stay the same? it's not very clear to me how the python exe file can find the data file by looking at a fixed `__file__`, is there a documentation relevant to this? I couldn't find any...

Comment: I see, in the doc(https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pyinstaller/latest/pyinstaller.pdf) it did say `__file__` is preferred now, but sorry i still dont get why though, the doc also says `Therefore, locating a data file relative to the main script can be either
done directly using sys._MEIPASS or via the parent path of the __file__ inside the main script.` so if the json file was not found in the `sys._MEIPASS`, i suppose it wouldn't be found even using `__file__`, what if I call `sys._MEIPASS` every time i need the path variable, would that be staying up to date?

Comment: oh, the json file was already added when i built the .exe file with `pyinstaller --onefile -w .\main.py --add-data 'pos-service-account.json;.'`, the program was working fine (i.e. used the json file to send data), but a few days later the program threw error saying it cannot find the json file in `sys._MEIPASS`

Comment: @Sam  then there should be no reason why your script cannot find the jsonfile.... If you want further help create an [mre]